# Spring Boot Gradle project won't render on localhost on Docker Compose Container

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, docker-compose

I have a small SpringBoot + Mongodb + Gradle service running in my docker-compose container, docker-compose works as it should e.g. Images are there and containers are running but it will NOT render on localhost and I have run out of all ideas. It runs perfect on machine localhost:8080 there no problem there. I hope someone can help me.

Dockerfile

```
FROM amazoncorretto:17-alpine-jdk
ARG JAR_FILE=build/libs/*.jar
COPY ${JAR_FILE} app.jar
ENTRYPOINT [ "java","-jar","/app.jar" ]
```

application.yml

```
server:
  port: 5000:5000
  contextPath: /stock

spring:
  application:
    name: Stock
  data:
    mongodb:
      uri: mongodb://mongodb:27070/store_stock
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  sb-app:
    build: .
    container_name: "docker-app"
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
  mongodb: 
    image: mongo:latest
    container_name: "mongodb"
    ports:
      - 27070:27017
```

Error

```
    2023-11-22 16:03:52 2023-11-22T16:03:52.025Z  INFO 1 --- [localhost:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               
    : Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server localhost:27017
 
com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket
    at com.mongodb.connection.netty.NettyStream$OpenChannelFutureListener.operationComplete(NettyStream.java:514) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.9.1.jar!/:na]
    at com.mongodb.connection.netty.NettyStream$OpenChannelFutureListener.operationComplete(NettyStream.java:487) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.9.1.jar!/:na]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:590) ~[netty-common-4.1.100.Final.jar!/:4.1.100.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners0(DefaultPromise.java:583) ~[netty-common-4.1.100.Final.jar!/:4.1.100.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:559) ~[netty-common-4.1.100.Final.jar!/:4.1.100.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:492) ~[netty-common-4.1.100.Final.jar!/:4.1.100.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setValue0(DefaultPromise.java:636) ~[netty-common-4.1.100.Final.jar!/:4.1.100.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setFailure0(DefaultPromise.java:629) ~[netty-common-4.1.100.Final.jar!/:4.1.100.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.tryFailure(DefaultPromise.java:118) ~[netty-common-4.1.100.Final.jar!/:4.1.100.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.fulfillConnectPromise(AbstractNioChannel.java:321) ~[netty-transport-4.1.100.Final.jar!/:4.1.100.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:337) ~[netty-transport-4.1.100.Final.jar!/:4.1.100.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:776) ~[netty-transport-4.1.100.Final.jar!/:4.1.100.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:724) ~[netty-transport-4.1.100.Final.jar!/:4.1.100.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:650) ~[netty-transport-4.1.100.Final.jar!/:4.1.100.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:562) ~[netty-transport-4.1.100.Final.jar!/:4.1.100.Final]
   at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997) ~[netty-common-4.1.100.Final.jar!/:4.1.100.Final]
   at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[netty-common-4.1.100.Final.jar!/:4.1.100.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[netty-common-4.1.100.Final.jar!/:4.1.100.Final]
  at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840) ~[na:na]
 Caused by: io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: localhost/127.0.0.1:27017
 Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
     at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnect(Native Method) ~[na:na]          
        ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel your root cause is explained here from stack trace

```
Caused by: io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: localhost/127.0.0.1:27017
 Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
     at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnect(Native Method) ~[na:na]
```

Connection refused means 2 things

- Your application failed to start hence not accessible (this failure can be of any reason)
- Your application dont have any issues, but the port is not free but occupied by some other process. (A quick way to prove this is to try running it on some other port)

Try to find if the port is in use.
for e.g on mac os

```
sudo lsof -i :27017
```

Once you find the process, then kill it

```
kill -9 <PID>
```

Another possibility is, your spring boot app is loading and trying to connect to mongo, but by this time mongo container is not up and running.
To fix this, you can define dependencies between services using `depends_on:` in docker-compose.yml

And also puts a healthcheck on the mongodb service to wait for become healthy.

Your updated docker-compose.yml should read like below

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  sb-app:
    depends_on:
      mongodb:
        condition: service_healthy
    build: .
    container_name: docker-app
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
  mongodb:
    image: mongo:latest
    healthcheck:
      test: nc -z mongodb 27017
      interval: 5s
    container_name: mongodb
    ports:
      - 27070:27017
```